# Jbuilder without the .json extension

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

Doing `http://localhost:3000/options/audio`

And I get error:

```
Missing template options/audio, application/audio with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/QuranAPI/app/views"
```

When I do `http://localhost:3000/options/audio.json`

That renders my Jbuilder file and the desired json. How can I render my jbuilder template with the .json extension?

Answer (score 3):

The jbuilder documentation tells you to create your jbuilder template as a `*.json.jbuilder` file. This makes the route look for the .json extension. If you remove the .json part and make your file `*.jbuilder` you will be able to go to the route without the .json extension.

Example:

`Filename: index.jbuilder
route: get 'ticket', to: 'tickets#index'`

Answer (score 0):

`jbuilder` is a gem, a tool.... I haven't tried it but if you want default functionality (html) with `json` and `jbuilder`, then:

```
http://localhost:3000/options/audio
```

will look for

```
/Users/mmahalwy/Desktop/Code/quran.com/QuranAPI/app/views/.../audio.html.jbuilder
```

So, you can put your code in there... But it can only be jbuilder code... Otherwise, you can use a plain `html.erb` or other file with embedded ruby and you will specify jbuilder json creation in it:

```
Jbuilder.encode do |json| # this is implied in .jbuilder files but can be used in any other ruby file
     json.xxx @yyy.xxx
     #....
end
```

Comment: Actually I ended up answering my own question. Instead of `name.json.jbuilder`, I need to just do `name.jbuilder` and no `respond_to` block will default to the jbuilder template.

Comment: `name.jbuilder` and `name.html.jbuilder` will do exactly the same thing. `respond_to` format html ONLY is not necessary to write.